# Securing a wysiwyg editor - is HTMLPurifier really the only way to go?

Tags: php, xss, wysiwyg, strip-tags

I have a comments form that is currently plaintext. This is nice and easy because I can just strip anything vaguely resembling HTML out of it using strip_tags and htmlspecialchars the rest.

However, There are plans to turn this into a HTML form with support for several tags `<a><b><p><h3>`...etc.

The problem I see is that even strip_tag'ing the input and keeping those tags only would still leave me open to XSS and jscript inside the tags.

I know that HTML Purifier can be used to fix this, but it looks really bulky, slow and I'm finding it hard to believe that there isn't a better way?

I had considered using a BBCode editor instead, but assuming that these insert code into the database as BB, how would I then convert it from BB back to HTML in order to display it?

Comment: Why not some simple BBcode parser?

Comment: What's wrong with HTML purifier? Speed is very unlikely to be an actual issue. And it's bulky because, well, sanitizing HTML id a complex matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do consider another time if you have the time and effort to write you own validation scheme, as this is pretty complex.

For one, take a look at what happens if you do not use recursion.

Badword : CopyThis

```
CopyCopyThisThis
```

Which leaves you with

```
CopyThis
```

The bad word...

Comment: It was to highlight some of the typical issues which many do not consider when sanitizing or stripping tags/attributes/etc.

Answer (score 1):

**BBCode** is indeed a very easy and useful solution for your problem.

I am using [MarkItUp! editor](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/), but you can surely find many others.

> how would I then convert it from BB back to HTML in order to display it?

The answer is simple: You can use `preg_replace` for it.

I implemented this a while back myself, so I can let you use my parser code. It translates the basic tags, as well as some custom ones like `[center]`. It's really easy to add your own tags or replace the current ones.

The script consists of a huge array with regexes and replacements, and one `preg_replace` call.

```
function replaceBBcode($str) {
    $replace = array(

        // inline text formats
        '/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is'                         => '<b>$1</b>',
        '/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/is'                         => '<i>$1</i>',
        '/\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/is'                         => '<u>$1</u>',
        '/\[s\](.*?)\[\/s\]/is'                         => '<s>$1</s>',
        '/\[sup\](.*?)\[\/sup\]/is'                     => '<sup>$1</sup>',
        '/\[sub\](.*?)\[\/sub\]/is'                     => '<sub>$1</sub>',

        // headings
        '/\[h1\](.*?)\[\/h1\]/is'                       => '<h1>$1</h1>',
        '/\[h2\](.*?)\[\/h2\]/is'                       => '<h2>$1</h2>',
        '/\[h3\](.*?)\[\/h3\]/is'                       => '<h3>$1</h3>',
        '/\[h4\](.*?)\[\/h4\]/is'                       => '<h4>$1</h4>',
        '/\[h5\](.*?)\[\/h5\]/is'                       => '<h5>$1</h5>',

        // formatting tags
        '/\[(?:hr|line)\]/is'                           => '<hr />',
        '/\[br\/?\]/is'                                 => '<br />',

        // links
        '/\[url=([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/is'            => '<a href="$1">$2</a>',
        '/\[link=([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[\/link\]/is'          => '<a href="$1">$2</a>',
        '/\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/is'                     => '<a href="$1" title="$1">$1</a>',
        '/\[link\](.*?)\[\/link\]/is'                   => '<a href="$1" title="$1">$1</a>',

        '/\[img=([^\]]+)\]/is'                          => '<img src="$1" alt="" />',

        // text blocks and block formats
        '/\[font=([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[\/font\]/is'          => '<span style="font-family: $1;">$2</span>',
        '/\[size=([0-9]+)\](.*?)\[\/size\]/is'          => '<span style="font-size: $1pt;">$2</span>',
        '/\[color=([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[\/color\]/is'        => '<span style="color: $1;">$2</span>',
        '/\[bgcolor=([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[\/bgcolor\]/is'    => '<span style="background-color: $1;">$2</span>',
        '/\[p\](.*?)\[\/p\]/is'                         => '<p>$1</p>',

        // alignment blocks
        '/\[align=(left|center|right|justify)\](.*?)\[\/align\]/is'     => '<div style="text-align: $1;">$2</div>',
        '/\[center\](.*?)\[\/center\]/is'               => '<div style="text-align: center;">$1</div>',
        '/\[left\](.*?)\[\/left\]/is'                   => '<div style="text-align: left;">$1</div>',
        '/\[right\](.*?)\[\/right\]/is'                 => '<div style="text-align: right;">$1</div>',
        '/\[justify\](.*?)\[\/justify\]/is'             => '<div style="text-align: justify;">$1</div>',

        // lists
        '/\[list=(disc|circle|square)\](.*?)\[\/list\]/is'  => '<ul style="list-style-type:$1;">$2</ul>',
        '/\[list\](.*?)\[\/list\]/is'                   => '<ul>$1</ul>',
        '/\[list=a\](.*?)\[\/list\]/s'                  => '<ol style="list-style-type:lower-alpha;">$1</ol>',
        '/\[LIST=a\](.*?)\[\/LIST\]/s'                  => '<ol style="list-style-type:lower-alpha;">$1</ol>',
        '/\[list=A\](.*?)\[\/list\]/s'                  => '<ol style="list-style-type:upper-alpha;">$1</ol>',
        '/\[LIST=A\](.*?)\[\/LIST\]/s'                  => '<ol style="list-style-type:upper-alpha;">$1</ol>',
        '/\[list=1\](.*?)\[\/list\]/is'                 => '<ol style="list-style-type:decimal;">$1</ol>',
        '/\[list=I\](.*?)\[\/list\]/is'                 => '<ol style="list-style-type:upper-roman;">$1</ol>',
        '/\[\*\]/is'                                    => '<li>',

        // videos
        '/\[(?:youtube|video|media|movie){1}\](?:https?\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/watch\?v=|youtube\.com\/v\/|youtu\.be\/)?([a-z0-9\-\_]+)\[\/(?:youtube|video|media|movie){1}\]/is'
                    => '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    );

    // do the tags
    $str = preg_replace (array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $str);  

    return $str; 
}
```

This will, however, not work good for nested tags. To replace a code with nested tags, I am using a loop like this:

```
$str = "... text to process ...";

// remove unwanted tags
$str = strip_tags($str);

// make entities of special chars (not quotes) 
$str = htmlentities($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, $encoding = 'UTF-8');

$str_old="";

do {
    $str_old=$str;
    $str=replaceBBcode($str);
} while ($str_old != $str);

// now $str contains the final html tags
```

Comment: Is this secure against XSS vulnerabilities though, which is the OPs main concern? I doesn't look like it.

Comment: What if I did `[right\]<script>alert("Ha!");</script>[\/right\]`?

Comment: Of course you should send the input through strip_tags first, before even saving it to database. This code is just the rendering part.

Comment: ahh, I see. So you would have BBCode as the input language instead of HTML. Fair enough

Comment: Yes. Now I also edited the post to include some security stuff, as you pointed out.